# Recursive expression parsing in Sprache

Tags: c#, parsing, sprache

I am building a Sprache parser to parse expressions similar to SQL search conditions.  e.g `Property = 123` or `Property > AnotherProperty`

So far both of those examples work, however I am struggling to figure out what I need to do to allow ANDing/ORing conditions and parenthesis.

Basically I have this so far:

```
private static readonly Parser<string> Operators =
    Parse.String("+").Or(Parse.String("-")).Or(Parse.String("="))
        .Or(Parse.String("<")).Or(Parse.String(">"))
        .Or(Parse.String("<=")).Or(Parse.String(">=")).Or(Parse.String("<>"))
        .Text();

private static readonly Parser<IdentifierExpression> Identifier = 
    from first in Parse.Letter.Once()
    from rest in Parse.LetterOrDigit.Many()
    select new IdentifierExpression(first.Concat(rest).ToArray());

public static readonly Parser<Expression> Integer =
    Parse.Number.Select(n => new IntegerExpression {Value = int.Parse(n)});

public static readonly Parser<SearchCondition> SearchCondition = 
    from left in Identifier.Or(Number)
    from op in Operators.Token()
    from right in Identifier.Or(Number)
    select new SearchCondition { Left = left, Right = right, Operator = op};
```

This works for the simple cases above, but now I need a pointer on how to implement conditions like:

- `PropertyX = PropertyY OR PropertyX = PropertyZ`
- `PropertyA > PropertyB AND (OtherAnotherProperty = 72 OR OtherAnotherProperty = 150)`

Can anyone give me an idea on how to structure the parsers for this sort of thing?

Comment: What is `IdentifierExpression`?  Custom LINQ Expression to access your data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have so far is a basic comparison expression parser.  It looks like you want to wrap that in a parser that handles logical expressions (`and`, `or`, etc.) with sub-expression support.

The code I posted at first was ripped from poorly-tested code I was still working on, which didn't handle statements with multiple terms.  My understanding of the `ChainOperator` method was clearly incomplete.

`Parse.ChainOperator` is the method that lets you specify your operators and have them appear 0-to-many times in the expression.  I was making assumptions about how it worked that turned out to be just wrong.

I've rewritten the code and added a few bits to make it easier to use:

```
// Helpers to make access simpler
public static class Condition
{
    // For testing, will fail all variable references
    public static Expression<Func<object, bool>> Parse(string text)
        => ConditionParser<object>.ParseCondition(text);

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Parse<T>(string text)
        => ConditionParser<T>.ParseCondition(text);

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Parse<T>(string text, T instance)
        => ConditionParser<T>.ParseCondition(text);
}

public static class ConditionParser<T>
{
    static ParameterExpression Parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "_");

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ParseCondition(string text)
        => Lambda.Parse(text);

    static Parser<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> Lambda =>
        OrTerm.End().Select(body => Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, Parm));

    // lowest priority first
    static Parser<Expression> OrTerm =>
        Parse.ChainOperator(OpOr, AndTerm, Expression.MakeBinary);

    static Parser<ExpressionType> OpOr = MakeOperator("or", ExpressionType.OrElse);

    static Parser<Expression> AndTerm =>
        Parse.ChainOperator(OpAnd, NegateTerm, Expression.MakeBinary);

    static Parser<ExpressionType> OpAnd = MakeOperator("and", ExpressionType.AndAlso);

    static Parser<Expression> NegateTerm =>
        NegatedFactor
        .Or(Factor);

    static Parser<Expression> NegatedFactor =>
        from negate in Parse.IgnoreCase("not").Token()
        from expr in Factor
        select Expression.Not(expr);

    static Parser<Expression> Factor =>
        SubExpression
        .Or(BooleanLiteral)
        .Or(BooleanVariable);

    static Parser<Expression> SubExpression =>
        from lparen in Parse.Char('(').Token()
        from expr in OrTerm
        from rparen in Parse.Char(')').Token()
        select expr;

    static Parser<Expression> BooleanValue =>
        BooleanLiteral
        .Or(BooleanVariable);

    static Parser<Expression> BooleanLiteral =>
        Parse.IgnoreCase("true").Or(Parse.IgnoreCase("false"))
        .Text().Token()
        .Select(value => Expression.Constant(bool.Parse(value)));

    static Parser<Expression> BooleanVariable =>
        Parse.Regex(@"[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\d]*").Token()
        .Select(name => VariableAccess<bool>(name));

    static Expression VariableAccess<TTarget>(string name)
    {
        MemberInfo mi = typeof(T).GetMember(name, MemberTypes.Field | MemberTypes.Property, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).FirstOrDefault();
        var targetType = typeof(TTarget);
        var type = 
            (mi is FieldInfo fi) ? fi.FieldType : 
            (mi is PropertyInfo pi) ? pi.PropertyType : 
            throw new ParseException($"Variable '{name}' not found.");

        if (type != targetType)
            throw new ParseException($"Variable '{name}' is type '{type.Name}', expected '{targetType.Name}'");

        return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Parm, mi);
    }

    // Helper: define an operator parser
    static Parser<ExpressionType> MakeOperator(string token, ExpressionType type)
        => Parse.IgnoreCase(token).Token().Return(type);
}
```

And some examples:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Parser with no input
        var condition1 = Condition.Parse("true and false or true");
        Console.WriteLine(condition1.ToString());
        var fn1 = condition1.Compile();
        Console.WriteLine("\t={0}", fn1(null));

        // Parser with record input
        var record1 = new { a = true, b = false };
        var record2 = new { a = false, b = true };
        var condition2 = Condition.Parse("a and b or not a", record);
        Console.WriteLine(condition2.ToString());
        var fn2 = condition2.Compile();
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} => {1}", record1.ToString(), fn2(record1));
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} => {1}", record2.ToString(), fn2(record2));
    }
}
```

---

You will still need to add your own parsers for handling comparison expressions and so on.  Plug those into the `BooleanValue` parser after the existing terms:

```
static Parser<Expression> BooleanValue => 
    BooleanLiteral
    .Or(BooleanVariable)
    .Or(SearchCondition);
```

I'm doing something similar with a more C#-style filter specification with type checking during the parse phase and separate parsers for strings vs numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Corey... unless I am missing something this will not parse expressions like `true and false or true` - it will only handle two expressions (obviously two is fine for true/false but I would want to handle any number of conditions (e.g `Prop1 = A AND Prop2 = B AND Prop3 = C`)

Comment: Well damn.  I thought I tested that.  Will fix and update the answer.

Comment: Done.  Incidentally this is based on the structure used in SimpleCalc.  I just changed some things to handle boolean conditions instead of arithmetic.  At some point I'll post the stuff I'm working on to GitHub.

Comment: Well, thank you Sir.  That is very good.  I also found this https://github.com/anpv/SpracheTest/ which has a similar approach to you - now I just need to figure out how it all works :)  Thanks very much

Comment: Fairly sure the recursive magic happens in the `Parse.ChainOperator` code.  I haven't read the Sprache code enough to figure out how it works however.

Comment: _is the method that lets you specify your operators and have them appear 0-to-many times in the expression._ - well, its more like _appear at at least once or many times_ - parser `Parse.ChainOperator(Parse.Char('+'), Parse.Digit().Many(), (op, a, b) => ...)).Parse("1");`  (note that + appears zero times ;) ) will not work